# Is the following repository pattern properly applied?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Is this repository code written according to best practices? The Last Section I included it in the repository as well.

```
class HR_Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly  LoginDataContext dataContext;
    public HR_Repository(LoginDataContext dataContext)
    {
    this.dataContext = dataContext;
    }


    public void Commit()
    {
        dataContext.SubmitChanges();
    }

    public IList<T> FindAll()
    {
        var table = this.LookupTableFor(typeof(T));
        return table.Cast<T>().ToList();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Find()
    {
        var table = this.LookupTableFor(typeof(T));
        return table.Cast<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        var table = this.LookupTableFor(typeof(T));
        table.InsertOnSubmit(item);
    }   

    public void Delete(T item)
    {
        var table = this.LookupTableFor(typeof(T));
        table.DeleteOnSubmit(item);
    }

    private ITable LookupTableFor(Type entityType)
    {
        return dataContext.GetTable(entityType);
    }
}


public static class UserQueries
{
    public static Employee ByUserName(this IQueryable<Employee> employees, string username)
    {
        return employees.Where(u => u.User_Name == username).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't feel like compiling this, but I assume that it must not work? That seems to be why this was closed, since its clearly written. I rather wish someone who cared enough to close this would explain what the problem is.

Comment: Agreed.  This at least deserves an explanation.  At a glance, I don't see why this wouldn't compile, but I don't have a C# compiler on my home machine.

Comment: It works.  I guarantee it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the underscore in the class name, `HR_Repository`. It's a generic name for a *generic class*, which is good, but seeing that it *implements* `IRepository<T>` I would expect something like this:

```
public class EmployeeRepository : IRepository<Employee>
```

I like that you're initializing your `private readonly LoginDataContext` in the constructor, from a constructor argument.

```
private readonly  LoginDataContext dataContext;
public HR_Repository(LoginDataContext dataContext)
{
    this.dataContext = dataContext;
}
```

I like it because this implementation of `IRepository<T>` has a *dependency* on the `LoginDataContext` - by passing it into the constructor, you're doing *constructor injection* and that's awesome. Ideally the dependency would be an *abstraction* (abstract class or interface), which makes it easier to inject as a *mock* or *fake* implementation when you're writing unit tests. Even if you never write these tests, the fact that your code would be *testable* is a very good thing.

I don't like that your static helper provides extension methods to `IQueryable<Employee>`, it's not clear how/where this code is being used, the benefits aren't immediately apparent.

---

As for the pattern itself, it looks like a hybrid Unit-of-Work / Repository implementation, because of the `Commit` method. But your implementation exposes `ITable` and `IQueryable`, which leaks out the ORM into the calling code.

If you consider the *client* as, say, a *controller* class (assuming MVC), the controller would have a dependency on the *unit-of-work*, which has a dependency on the *data context* and lets you work with one or more *repositories*, which all share the data context of the unit-of-work:

[image: UoW+Repository]

<sub>(I skipped UML classes, hope this doesn't look too weird)</sub>

---

> **Disclaimer**
>
> I'm biased. I'm not a fan of unit-of-work/repository pattern, at least not with Entity Framework. I think Entity Framework's `DbContext` *is a* unit-of-work, and the `IDbSet<TEntity>` properties it exposes *are* repositories - I think wrapping this in another level of abstraction has very little benefits and adds a considerable amount of complexity to the code.
>
> Instead, I simply wrap `DbContext` with an interface:
>
> ```
> public interface IUnitOfWork
> {
>     void SaveChanges();
>     IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>();
> }
>
> public class MyContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
> {
>     IDbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> Then I usually have a "service" class that takes an `IUnitOfWork` dependency; I write closely related queries inside that class, but the "service" only returns materialized results, it doesn't expose `IQueryable<T>`, even less so `ITable`. A controller will take a factory that can instantiate such a "service", wrapping its instance in a `using` block to ensure proper disposal.

Comment: Here's some rantage from the great and powerful Rob Conery supporting your distaste for unit-of-work+repository: http://www.wekeroad.com/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/